# On equation $e^{xy-yx}=e^xe^ye^{-x}e^{-y}$ in $C^*$ algebras

Tags: oa.operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

Inspired by [this MSE  question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3383009/on-equation-exp-x-y-exp-x-exp-y-on-a-lie-group-and-its-lie-algebra) we ask the following question:

Is there a noncommutative $C^*$-algebra $A$ for which the following identity holds for all $x,y \in A$?

$$e^{(xy-yx)}= e^xe^y e^{-x}e^{-y}$$

That is $$e^{[x,y]}=[e^x,e^y]$$
where the bracket on the left-hand side is the algebra commutator, and the bracket on the right-hand side denotes the group commutator.

Comment: @YemonChoi  the left commutator is an  an algebra commutator but the right one is a group commutator. So it holds for all commutative algebra. The equation in the title is misleading please read the equation in the body of the post.

Comment: @YemonChoi motivation is added

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I have reworded the title in case anyone makes the same error as I did

Comment: @YemonChoi I thank you too for your revision.

Comment: [deleted over hasty attempt at an answer, I need to revisit this]

Comment: I would expect that the Baker-Campbell-Hausdorff formula could be used to say that $A$ is commutative; failing that, that for every $X, Y$ we have that $[X, Y]$ commutes with $X$ and $Y$. Have you tried it?

Comment: Taylor at order 3 $[+O(\|x\|^4+\|y\|^4)]$ yields that a unital Banach algebra with this identity has to be 2-step nilpotent (that is $[x,y]$) is central for all $x,y$);  indeed it says that $[x,[x,y]]$ is zero, which by polarization gives the result.

Comment: @YCor I think it may be worth noting that the Jacobi identity is needed, that is, that polarization doesn't quite give the result directly. The derivation is straightforward, but not immediate.

Comment: @user44191 polarization gives $[x,[y,z]]+[y,[x,z]]=0$ (for all $x,y,z$). This can be rewritten as $[y,[z,x]]=-[x,[y,z]]$, and iterating 3 times we get $[x,[y,z]]=-[y,[z,x]]=[z,[x,y]]=-[x,[y,z]]$. Hence if $2$ is invertible (the question is over $\mathbf{C}$) we get $[x,[y,z]]=0$ without using Jacobi.

Comment: Conversely BCH for a unital Banach algebra satisfying $[x,[x,y]]=0$ identically writes as $\exp(x)\exp(y)=\exp(x+y+\frac12[xy])$ and this gives the commutator identity. So a unital Banach algebra satisfies the given commutator identity iff its underlying Lie algebra is 2-step nilpotent. What remains is to determine whether a $C^*$-algebra whose underlying Lie algebra is 2-step nilpotent is necessarily commutative.

Comment: ... oh, but the latter is already solved here :https://mathoverflow.net/a/299943/14094. I'll post an answer.

Comment: @YCor I think you made a sign error when switching $x$ and $z$ in the inner bracket? $[x,[y,z]]+[y,[x,z]]=0$ becomes $[x,[y,z]]−[y,[z,x]]=0$, or $[x,[y,z]]=[y,[z,x]]$. You get equality when cycling, and sign change when switching any 2 of the 3, if I'm not mistaken. Which leads to using Jacobi and needing $3$ to not be a $0$-divisor, but $2$ is free.

Comment: @user44191 you're right, thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes:

> A $C^*$-algebra satisfies the identity $e^{[xy-yx]}=e^xe^ye^{-x}e^{-y}$ iff it is commutative.

This follows from two independent facts (I write $[x,y]=xy-yx$)

> 1) A (real/complex) unital Banach algebra satisfies the identity $e^{[xy-yx]}=e^xe^ye^{-x}e^{-y}$ $\Leftrightarrow$ it satisfies the identity $[x,[x,y]]=0$ $\Leftrightarrow$ it satisfies the identity $[x,[y,z]]$, i.e., its underlying Lie algebra is 2-step nilpotent.
>
> 2) A $C^*$-algebra satisfying the identity $[x,[x,y]]=0$ is commutative.

For (1), one obtains that the main implication, namely the identity implies $[x,[x,y]]=0$, by a 3rd order Taylor expansion: in every Banach algebra one has 
$$e^{xy-yx}=1+xy-yx+o(\|x\|^3+\|y\|^3);$$
$$e^xe^ye^{-x}e^{-y}=1+xy-yx+\frac12([x+y,[x,y]])+o(\|x\|^3+\|y\|^3),$$
so the commutator identity forces $[x+y,[x,y]]=0$ for all $x,y$, and hence $[x,[x,y]$ identically vanishes by homogeneity.

(As mentioned in the comments, a simple argument then implies $[x,[y,z]]=0$ for all $x,y,z$, but this is not needed to run the argument.)

Conversely, if $[x,[x,y]]$ is identically zero, the Baker-Campbell-Hausdorff formula reads as: for all $x,y$, one has $\exp(x)\exp(y)=\exp(x+y+(1/2)[x,y])$. The commutator identity follows.

Let us pass to (2). Let $A$ be a $C^*$-algebra satisfying the PI-identity $[x,[x,y]]=0$. First, if $A$ is finite-dimensional, it is a product of matrix algebras, and hence is commutative (since the given identity fails for $M_n(\mathbf{C})$ for $n\ge 2$). In general, I need the last emphasized statement in [my answer here](https://mathoverflow.net/a/299943/14094): $A$ has a family $(J_i)$ of finite-codimensional 2-sided closed $*$-ideals with trivial intersection (so $A$ embeds into the product $\prod_i A/J_i$). By the finite-dimensional case, $A/J_i$ is commutative for every $i$. Hence $A$ is commutative.

Comment: I think your 3rd order Taylor expansion can't be right; there should be some symmetry between $x$ and $y$, which should force a term of the form $[x, [x, y]]$; this can also be seen by looking at the inverse (which takes the form $e^y e^x e^{-y} e^{-x}$). This can be dealt with by slightly more careful manipulation of the coefficients of $x$ and $y$, though.

Comment: @user44191 Thanks! I had actually selected one of two homogeneous terms in my draft, then forgot the other one. It indeed yields $[x+y,[x,y]]$. Corrected.